# Onsen UI with vuejs installation error

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs2, onsen-ui, monaca

Im trying to get started with onsenUI vue.
when trying to create a new project with monaca like this:

`monaca create helloworld`

and selecting onsenui-v2-vue-splitter template, it gives me an error like this:

```
npm WARN package.json onsenui-v2-vue-splitter@2.2.7+20170328.1 No description
npm WARN package.json onsenui-v2-vue-splitter@2.2.7+20170328.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json onsenui-v2-vue-splitter@2.2.7+20170328.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json onsenui-v2-vue-splitter@2.2.7+20170328.1 No license field.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency onsenui@~2.4.0 included from vue-onsenui will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
Error occurred while creating project: Failed to install template dependencies.
```

My npm version is 3.10.10

Any Ideas how can I fix this?
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error, you failed to install the template dependencies. Please follow the step-by-step instruction on [Getting Started with Vue 2 & Onsen UI 2 Template](https://docs.monaca.io/en/monaca_cli/samples/vue_onsen/#monaca-cli-vue2).